# How to to make the canvas scrollable to contain multiple pages scanned pdf?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, pdf, canvas

I'm beginner to HTML5.

I use the [Canvas](http://www.codicode.com/art/how_to_draw_on_a_html5_canvas_with_a_mouse.aspx) to draw on it and i want to get the following abilities :

---

1. Allowing the canvas to be Expandable so if the image was set of `scanned pdfs`, i can show all the images (pdf pages).
2. I want the (Undo & Redo ) Functionality through the canvas .

Comment: This are requests for the HTML8 :). Probably you need to have two canvas, one hidden that keep the previous state and make the undo, and for the expand, to make a new one with new size and copy to that the old one with the older size. With other words I do not think that this functionality exist - you need to create it.

Comment: Undo and redo is possible, though I'm not quite sure how to implement it. Check out [deviantArt Muro](http://muro.deviantart.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this before by storing the canvas state using the toDataUrl method to an undo_array :

```
var undo_array = [];
```

so before any change you do  :

```
undo_array.push(myCanvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
```

now, when the undo button is pressed, just restore the previous picture :

```
var myImg = new Image();
oImg.onload = function() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvasID").getContext("2d");       
  ctx.drawImage(myImg, 0, 0);
}
myImg.src = undo_array.pop();
```

but if you also change the canvas's seize, i guess you can use another array to store/restore seize changes.

Comment: Typo: 'myImg' instead of 'oImg'.